# The int values i send throug socket is different from int values received (Java)

Tags: java, sockets, integer, inputstream, outputstream

I'm sending 2 int values on the outputstream of a socket, running on an android studio project using JDK8, by doing this :

```
        try {
            System.out.println("AFTER THREAD START");
            System.out.println("WRITE AGE : " + age + " WRITED SEX : " + sex);
            output_stream_request.writeInt(age);
            output_stream_request.writeInt(sex);
            output_stream_request.flush();
            System.out.println("WRITE AGE : " + age + " WRITED SEX : " + sex);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And i receive them on the input side, on a ant project using JDK8, by doing this :

```
try {
            System.out.println("BEFORE_READ");
            boolean valid_data = false;
            int age = 0;
            int sex = 0 ;

            age = connector.get_dis_request().readInt();
            sex = connector.get_dis_request().readInt();
            System.out.println("AGE : " + age + " SEX : " + sex );
```

I executed it many times with different values and i got those results :

SENDING : 
AGE : 50 
SEX : 200
// RECEIVING :
AGE : -1174405120
SEX : 838860800

SENDING : 
AGE : 50 
SEX : 201
// RECEIVING (same as above):
AGE : -1174405120
SEX : 838860800

SENDING : 
AGE : 2 
SEX : 200
// RECEIVING :
AGE : -1174405120
SEX : 33554432

SENDING : 
AGE : 2 
SEX : 201
// RECEIVING (same as above):
AGE : -1174405120
SEX : 33554432

note that the age value received never change 
and the sex received is probably related to the age value sent as their changing values.
I checked the value with the debugger after the printed ones and they were the same so its not a printing problem.

Comment: You did not mention the types of the Java streams involved on either side.  So we can't advise on why your code is not working, or the correct methods to use.

Answer (score 0):

Using simple .write() and .read() resolved my problem.

Comment: But why?  Sorry, but an answer that simply gives a fix without explaining it does not help other readers much.  There was a reason that your original version did not work, and people need to understand what that was ... so that they can decide if your putative fix is going to be correct for them.